# Can you install Ubuntu server on a disk partition?

Tags: server, system-installation, usb-installation

I have my partitions in Windows 10 like this:

[image: Disk partitions from Windows 10]

The "Lin" partition is unused, I am saving it for some other Linux. For the ubuntu server, I want to use the 31.25 GB free space.

Booting with the USB stick (since I don't want to use the whole drive), I get here:

[image: boot selection]

And then I have no idea what to do next.

Is it possible and how can I do it?

Comment: You always install grub2's boot loader to a drive. BIOS only boots from drive, not a partition. Since you have two drives, may be better to install grub to second drive, just to keep Windows boot loader on first drive. Grub only boots working Windows so sometimes you have to directly boot Windows. Easier then as you can choose first drive and boot it to fix Windows. Otherwise you have to use your Windows repair/recovery disk to fix Windows which you should also have anyway.

Comment: The first drive is SSD, the second is laptop HDD that I use for data.

Is there no way to have two OSes on the same drive?

Comment: You can have OS on same drive. Issue is Windows fast start up. Windows turns it on with updates & then grub will not boot it. And with BIOS, you then have to temporaily install Windows boot loader, fix Windows & then restore grub. But if boot loader on HDD, you can still boot Windows just by changing BIOS boot order. Windows 10  dual boots better in UEFI boot mode as then you always can directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu. Only a tiny part of grub, the boot loader in MBR, will be on HDD in first sector. Will not change your data on that drive.

Comment: I have really hard time understanding this.

I just need small installation of ubuntu server so that I can run octoprint to monitor my 3d printer with my laptop. I reserved for the linux partition of my drive.

I think you are saying that I should install the boot loader on the second ("data") drive and keep the rest on the SSD Partition?

How do I do that?

Comment: With desktop installer it is choose Something Else, select partition on SSD as / (root) and ext4, and choose boot loader location as HDD. Have not used new gui Server installer, but essentially the same process as all Linux installs use similar processes.

Comment: What I tried is install only root "/" on the "Free Space" and it ended with a pretty quick error.

I also tried creating new volume in win from that "Free Space",again chose to install only root there, and it ended with an error, however that one came a bit later.

Comment: You cannot create Linux partitions in Windows. Ubuntu only installs to Linux formats like ext4, current default partitioning with Ubuntu. There are many other formats, but not NTFS nor FAT32 for / (root). What was error on use of free space. It looks like you have MBR(msdos) partitioning with 4 partition limit? If you created new partitions with Windows did it convert to dynamic from basic? That is a one way conversion and does not work with Linux.

Comment: I chose the option to format it as ext4 during installation in both cases so this should not have been an issue.

Comment: When you choose the free space to use it, what error did you get?

Comment: it did not show any specific error, or I didnt see it. I had the option to see the full report, but I have no idea what to look for

Comment: IF no errors then it is working when you select the free space choose ext4 & / ?

Comment: It said: Sorry, there was a problem completing the installation

It did not mention any specific error and I had the choice to see the full report.